# Extract string if found using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Given myStr:
"The pressure is" or
"The number could be 4.4psi"

And the desired results:
"The pressure is" or
"The number could be"

```
result = /(.*?)\d+\..*/g.exec(myStr)[1].trim();
```

which will work on the second string but will throw an exception in the first.

> Cannot read property '1' of null.

How can I get the desired using regex? thx

Comment: What is your intention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use just:

```
str = str.replace(/\s*\d+\..*$/, '');
```

To replace all the text starting with a digit till end of line.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Sz3GId/2)

Answer (score 0):

`JavaScript` supports `\D` which might be useful here:

```
str = str.replace(/^(\D*).*/, '$1');
```

See [**an example on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/Ht4mLO/1/) (admittedly more sentences are needed though).